# Opening an alert function when permission is not 'granted'

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

In my code, you can see it starts by asking for the users location permission. When granted, it logs and displays the users latitude and longitude.

I am trying to have an alert pop up when the user declines this permission. I thought it would be as simple as what I have implemented in the code below but obviously something is wrong. I am calling my permissionAlert function in my if statement when status != granted.

I have included the code below as well as a snack example [here](https://snack.expo.dev/@priedejm/location).

Thank you for any insight at all.

```
export default function App() {
  const [latitude, setLatitude] = useState(null);
  const [longitude, setLongitude] = useState(null);
  

  const permissionAlert = () => {
     Alert.alert(
      'You did not allow location permissions',
      [
        {text: 'Yes', onPress: () => console.log('Yes button clicked')},
        {text: 'No', onPress: () => console.log('No button clicked'), style: 'cancel'},
      ],
      { 
        cancelable: true 
      }
    );
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      
      let { status } = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();
      if (status !== 'granted') {
        permissionAlert();
        return;
      }

      let location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});
      setLatitude(location.coords.latitude)
      setLongitude(location.coords.longitude);
    })();
  }, []);


  console.warn("latitude: ", latitude);
  console.warn("longitude: ", longitude);
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.paragraph}>{latitude}</Text>
      <Text style={styles.paragraph}>{longitude}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're not using the [Alert API](https://reactnative.dev/docs/alert#alert) correctly.

Alerts 2nd argument is `description`, but you are trying to pass in an array of actions, which should be 3rd argument instead.

So it should be something like [this](https://snack.expo.dev/5oyf0YUbz)

```
 Alert.alert(
     'Permission denined',
      'You did not allow location permissions',
      [
        {text: 'Yes', onPress: () => console.log('Yes button clicked')},
        {text: 'No', onPress: () => console.log('No button clicked'), style: 'cancel'},
      ],
      { 
        cancelable: true 
      }
    );
```